# Styling <divs> with CSS3

Tags: html, css

I'm able to align and center graphpaper and footer as needed but I'm unable to get the colorpicker div to exist next to these to.  No matter what I try it ends up being below the rest of these.  Is there a way to have the two divs centered vertically and then put the colorpicker div next to these two?

```
<div id="abstract">
   <div class="graphpaper" id="graphpaper" onclick="getPosition(event)" style="width:984px; height:1100px;">
      <img src="images/poster/poster-top.png" align="left"/>
      <img src="images/poster/poster-left.jpg" align="left" style="margin-left:12px;"/>
      <canvas id ="canvas" width = "898" height = "900"/>
      <img src="images/poster/poster-right.jpg" align="right" style="margin-right:10px;"/>        
</div>
<div class="footer" id="footer">
      <img src="images/poster/poster-bottom.png"/>
</div>
<div class="colorpicker" id="colorpicker" style="width: 70px; clear:both;">
    <img src="images/color-tab/no-color.png" id="unselected" class="unselected"/><br>
    <img src="images/color-tab/color-dark.png" id="dark_image" class="darkimage" 
   onclick="getColor('#00ccff','images/color-tab/color-dark.png')"/><br>
    <img src="images/color-tab/color-medium.png" id="med_image" class="medimage" 
   onclick="getColor('#000000','images/color-tab/color-medium.png')"/><br>
    <img src="images/color-tab/color_light.png" id="light_image" class="lightimage"     
   onclick="getColor('#ff0066','images/color-tab/color_light.png')"/><br><br><br><br>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you link me to the website where you're using this?

Comment: The website isn't up and running but I can jsFiddle.  Is there a way to upload images to jsFddle?

Comment: Upload them to an image hosting site like http://imageshack.us/ then use the URL

Comment: I'll do this after work.  I'll attach an image for you guys to see though.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this you need to float all of your divs to the left, and give them widths that add up to 100% (ie. 40%, 40%, 20%).

This is my best guess without seeing your question as a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

1.) Removed the Footer div and added the img to the graphpaper div
2.) set colorpicker to position:fixed; and set margin-top:300; so it would be starting in the proper place.